# Harry Potter books with discounts kata

Tags: c#

I have implemented a solution to the [Potter Kata](http://www.codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/index.pl?action=browse&id=KataPotter&revision=41). Basically, there are 5 different (types of) books, and the buyer gets a discount depending on how many different books he has bought. Multiple instances of the same book (type) don't get a discount.

The discount values are the following:

- 2 different books: 5%
- 3 different books: 10%
- 4 different books: 20%
- 5 different books: 25%

The difficulty in this kata comes from the jump in discount between 3 and 4 different books. I implemented a solution that - regarding the price algorithm - should be pretty easy to extend to more books and/or different discount values, but I fear that it's not very good code in general. That is, I think it's not easily extendable in itself, not in terms of the algorithm. One example for this is that I use a fixed number of book types (the array is initialized with `{0,0,0,0,0}`), though that would be the part that is easiest to fix; or that I hard-coded the discounts. I'm sure you'll find lots of other stuff to criticize/comment on, and I greatly appreciate it, especially tips on how to make these classes easier to extend!

This is something that was created in the last couple of hours, so don't expect a lot of optimization of the algorithm or reduction of unnecessary calls (I don't like my `IsFoo` properties in that regard). It's more about extensibility and general class and method design.

**PriceCalc.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Library class to calculate the price of BookBasket objects.
/// </summary>
public static class PriceCalc
{
  public const decimal SingleBookPrice = 8m;
  public const decimal PairDiscount = 0.95m;
  public const decimal TripletDiscount = 0.9m;
  public const decimal QuadrupletDiscount = 0.8m;
  public const decimal QuintupletDiscount = 0.75m;

  private static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<BookBasket, decimal> basicBasketsAndFactors = new ReadOnlyDictionary<BookBasket, decimal>(
    new Dictionary<BookBasket, decimal>
    {
      { new BookBasket(1), 1 },
      { new BookBasket(2), 1 },
      { new BookBasket(3), 1 },
      { new BookBasket(4), 1 },
      { new BookBasket(5), 1 },
      { new BookBasket(1,2), 2 * PairDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,3), 2 * PairDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,4), 2 * PairDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,5), 2 * PairDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(2,3), 2 * PairDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(2,4), 2 * PairDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(2,5), 2 * PairDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(3,4), 2 * PairDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(3,5), 2 * PairDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(4,5), 2 * PairDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,2,3), 3 * TripletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,2,4), 3 * TripletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,2,5), 3 * TripletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,3,4), 3 * TripletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,3,5), 3 * TripletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,4,5), 3 * TripletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(2,3,4), 3 * TripletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(2,3,5), 3 * TripletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(2,4,5), 3 * TripletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(3,4,5), 3 * TripletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,2,3,4), 4 * QuadrupletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,2,3,5), 4 * QuadrupletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,2,4,5), 4 * QuadrupletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,3,4,5), 4 * QuadrupletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(2,3,4,5), 4 * QuadrupletDiscount },
      { new BookBasket(1,2,3,4,5), 5 * QuintupletDiscount }
    });

  private static readonly Dictionary<BookBasket, decimal> calculatedPrices = new Dictionary<BookBasket, decimal>();

  /// <summary>   
  /// Calculates the price of a given BookBasket object recursively, and using memoization.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="basket">The basket.</param>
  /// <returns>The price of the basket.</returns>
  public static decimal Price(BookBasket basket)
  {
    if (basket.IsEmpty)
    {
      return 0;
    }
    else if (basket.IsBasic)
    {
      return basicBasketsAndFactors[basket] * SingleBookPrice;
    }
    else if (!basket.IsValid)
    {
      return decimal.MinValue;
    }
    else
    {
      return basicBasketsAndFactors
        .Keys
        .Select(basicBasket =>
          {
            BookBasket diff = basket - basicBasket;
            if (calculatedPrices.ContainsKey(diff))
            {
              return calculatedPrices[diff] + basicBasketsAndFactors[basicBasket] * SingleBookPrice;
            }
            else
            {
              decimal diffPrice = Price(diff);
              calculatedPrices.Add(diff, diffPrice);
              return diffPrice + basicBasketsAndFactors[basicBasket] * SingleBookPrice;
            }
          })
        .Where(x => x > 0)
        .Min();
    }
  }
}
```

I know I should probably get rid of the anonymous method in the LINQ statement, but I just hacked in the memoization there and then forgot it before pasting.

**BookBasket.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a basket of books.
/// </summary>
public class BookBasket
{
  #region Members

  private int[] storedBooks = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

  #endregion

  #region Constructors

  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a new instance of BookBasket.
  /// </summary>
  public BookBasket()
  {
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a new instance of BookBasket and fills it with books of given types/ID's.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="bookIds">The types/ID's of the books that are to be added.</param>
  public BookBasket(params int[] bookIds)
  {
    Add(bookIds);
  }

  #endregion

  #region Overloads

  /// <summary>
  /// Overload of the binary operator '-'. Subtracts BookBasket objects by subtracting the book
  /// counts ID-wise.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="first">The first BookBasket.</param>
  /// <param name="second">The second BookBasket.</param>
  /// <returns>A new BookBasket representing the subtraction result.</returns>
  public static BookBasket operator -(BookBasket first, BookBasket second)
  {
    var result = new BookBasket();
    for (int i = 0; i < first.storedBooks.Length; i++)
    {
      int diff = first.storedBooks[i] - second.storedBooks[i];
      result.storedBooks[i] = diff;
    }
    return result;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Checks for content-equality with another instance of BookBasket.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="obj">The other BookBasket.</param>
  /// <returns>True, if the two instances of BookBasket hold an identical collection of books; false otherwise.</returns>
  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    var other = obj as BookBasket;
    if (other != null)
    {
      var diff = this - other;
      return diff.IsEmpty;
    }
    else
    {
      return base.Equals(obj);
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a hash code for the BookBasket object.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>The hash code of the BookBasket.</returns>
  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return ToString().GetHashCode();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a string representation for the BookBasket object.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>The string representation of the BookBasket.</returns>
  public override string ToString()
  {
    string result = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < storedBooks.Length; i++)
    {
      result += storedBooks[i];
    }
    return result;
  }

  #endregion

  #region Properties

  /// <summary>
  /// True, if the basket contains only one instance or none of any book.
  /// </summary>
  public bool IsBasic
  {
    get
    {
      foreach (int count in storedBooks)
      {
        if (count != 1 && count != 0)
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// True, iff the basket contains no books (and no negative values).
  /// </summary>
  public bool IsEmpty
  {
    get
    {
      foreach (int count in storedBooks)
      {
        if (count != 0)
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// True, if there is no negative number of books.
  /// </summary>
  public bool IsValid
  {
    get
    {
      foreach (int count in storedBooks)
      {
        if (count < 0)
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  }

  #endregion

  #region Methods

  /// <summary>
  /// The number of books with a certain type/ID.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="bookId">The type/ID of the book.</param>
  /// <returns>The number of books of the given type.</returns>
  public int Count(int bookId)
  {
    return storedBooks[bookId - 1];
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Adds a book with a certain type/ID.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="bookId">The type/ID of the book.</param>
  public void Add(int bookId)
  {
    storedBooks[bookId - 1]++;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Adds multiple books, given by a list of ID's.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="bookIds">The ID's of the books to add.</param>
  public void Add(params int[] bookIds)
  {
    foreach (int id in bookIds)
    {
      Add(id);
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Empties the BookBasket s.t. every book has count zero.
  /// </summary>
  public void Clear()
  {
    storedBooks = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  }

  #endregion
}
```

**Test class:**

```
  [TestClass]
  public class Tests
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void BasketUtilityTests()
    {
      var basket = new BookBasket();

      basket.Add(1);
      Assert.AreEqual(1, basket.Count(1), "basket does not contain the correct number of books.");

      basket.Clear();
      Assert.IsTrue(basket.IsEmpty, "basket is not empty.");

      basket.Add(4, 4, 4);
      Assert.AreEqual(3, basket.Count(4), "basket does not contain the correct number of books.");

      basket.Clear();

      basket.Add(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5);
      var secondBasket = new BookBasket();
      secondBasket.Add(1, 2, 3, 5);
      var expected = new BookBasket();
      expected.Add(1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5);
      Assert.AreEqual(expected, basket - secondBasket);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void BasicPriceTests()
    {
      var basket = new BookBasket();

      Assert.AreEqual(0, PriceCalc.Price(basket));

      basket.Add(1);
      Assert.AreEqual(PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice, PriceCalc.Price(basket));

      basket.Clear();

      basket.Add(1, 1, 1);
      Assert.AreEqual(3 * PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice, PriceCalc.Price(basket));

      basket.Clear();

      basket.Add(2);
      Assert.AreEqual(PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice, PriceCalc.Price(basket));

      basket.Clear();

      basket.Add(3);
      Assert.AreEqual(PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice, PriceCalc.Price(basket));

      basket.Clear();

      basket.Add(4);
      Assert.AreEqual(PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice, PriceCalc.Price(basket));

      basket.Clear();

      basket.Add(5);
      Assert.AreEqual(PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice, PriceCalc.Price(basket));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SimpleDiscountTests()
    {
      var basket = new BookBasket();

      basket.Add(1, 2);
      Assert.AreEqual(2 * PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice * PriceCalc.PairDiscount, PriceCalc.Price(basket));

      basket.Clear();

      basket.Add(1, 3, 4);
      Assert.AreEqual(3 * PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice * PriceCalc.TripletDiscount, PriceCalc.Price(basket));

      basket.Clear();

      basket.Add(2, 3, 4, 5);
      Assert.AreEqual(4 * PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice * PriceCalc.QuadrupletDiscount, PriceCalc.Price(basket));

      basket.Clear();

      basket.Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
      Assert.AreEqual(5 * PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice * PriceCalc.QuintupletDiscount, PriceCalc.Price(basket));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SeveralDiscountsTest()
    {
      var basket = new BookBasket();

      basket.Add(1, 1, 2);
      decimal expected = (2 * PriceCalc.PairDiscount + 1) * PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice;
      Assert.AreEqual(expected, PriceCalc.Price(basket));

      basket.Clear();

      basket.Add(1, 1, 2, 2);
      expected = 2 * 2 * PriceCalc.PairDiscount * PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice;
      Assert.AreEqual(expected, PriceCalc.Price(basket));

      basket.Clear();

      basket.Add(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4);
      expected = (4 * PriceCalc.QuadrupletDiscount + 2 * PriceCalc.PairDiscount) * PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice;
      Assert.AreEqual(expected, PriceCalc.Price(basket));

      basket.Clear();

      basket.Add(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5);
      expected = (5 * PriceCalc.QuintupletDiscount + 1) * PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice;
      Assert.AreEqual(expected, PriceCalc.Price(basket));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void EdgeCaseOne()
    {
      var basket = new BookBasket(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5);

      decimal expected = 2 * 4 * PriceCalc.QuadrupletDiscount * PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice;
      decimal actual = PriceCalc.Price(basket);
      Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void EdgeCaseTwo()
    {
      var basket = new BookBasket(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5);

      decimal expected = 78.8m;
      decimal actual = PriceCalc.Price(basket);
      Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void EdgeCaseThree()
    {
      var basket = new BookBasket(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5);

      decimal expected = 100m;
      decimal actual = PriceCalc.Price(basket);
      Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void EdgeCaseFour()
    {
      var basket = new BookBasket(
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        3, 3, 3, 3,
        4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
        5, 5, 5, 5);
      decimal expected = (3 * 5 * PriceCalc.QuintupletDiscount + 2 * 4 * PriceCalc.QuadrupletDiscount) * PriceCalc.SingleBookPrice;
      decimal actual = PriceCalc.Price(basket);
      Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I suppose you also have code that [implements the tests](http://www.codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/index.pl?action=browse&id=KataPotter&revision=41)? Any chance you could also post that class?

Comment: @Jamal Just out of curiosity: Why did the title need to be changed? When creating the question I saw a lot of other ones actually still containing "kata". Would it maybe be appropriate to create a tag for that?

Comment: @InvisiblePanda: That is something you can propose on Meta.  But since the other questions have it, I can add it back for now.

Comment: I'd propose a more enticing title instead of the rather mundane "Harry Potter books with discounts", something along the lines of "Potter's magical book discounts". Perhaps throw in a reference to [Obscurus Books](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Obscurus_Books) or [Whizz Hard Books](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Whizz_Hard_Books)? ;-)

Comment: The code looks pretty and all - but hardcoding all the data just seems so redundant. Imagine for a second we live in a world where the Harry Potter series consists of 7 books. Imagine extending your code to fit that.

Comment: @Mads That's pretty much the reason why I'm asking. As I said, the actual algorithm is very easily adapted to a general setting, but I wonder how to design my classes accordingly. I could just give the number of books to the BookBasket class, or just let the user add arbitrary `bookId`s. The discount could be a dictionary using as a key the number of different books and as value the discount.

Comment: But there are so many other ways of approaching this that I don't know what a good place would be to start with. As you can see, I still have problems with dependencies in general. Well, I've got a bit of time today and maybe I'll be getting to generalize this a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the possibility to extend this code can only be achieved by using a more OO approach.

This could be achieved by adding a `Book` class which has at least an `Id`, a `Title`, a `Price` and a `DiscountId` property where the `DiscountId` holds a reference to a `DiscountInformation` object.

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public double Price { get; private set; }
    public int DiscountId { get; set; }

    public Book(int id, double price, int discountId = int.MinValue)
        : this(String.Empty, id, price, discountId)
    { }
    public Book(string title, int id, double price, int discountId = int.MinValue)
    {
        Title = title;
        Id = id;
        Price = price; 
        DiscountId = discountId;
    }
}
```

By adding a `DiscountInformation` class we can store the different discounts in relation to the number of different items.

```
public class DiscountInformation
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<int, double> Discounts { get; private set; }

    public DiscountInformation(int id)
    {
        Discounts = new Dictionary<int, double>();
        Id = id;
    }

    public DiscountInformation(int numberOfDifferentItems, double discount, int discountId)
        :this(discountId)
    {
        Discounts.Add(numberOfDifferentItems, discount);
    }

    public void AddDiscount(int numberOfDifferentItems, double discount)
    {
        if (Discounts.ContainsKey(numberOfDifferentItems)) { return; }
        Discounts.Add(numberOfDifferentItems, discount);
    }
}
```

Now we can store `DiscountInformation` objects in a `List`, a `Dictionary` or a database for retrieval of the disounts for a list of books with the same value of `DiscountId`.

Next we can replace the `private int[] storedBooks = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };` of the `BookBasket` class with a `List<Book>` or better a `Dictionary<Book, int>` for storing a book and the amount of this book, which adds the possibility to remove the restriction of storing only up to 5 different books.

We need to override the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods in the `Book` class to use a `Book` object as the key of a `Dictionary`.

For calculating the total price of the books contained in the `BookBasket` we need to group the books by using the `DiscountId` property add the sum of the prices of the books and multiply the sum by the discount retrieved from the `DiscountInformation` by using the `DiscountId` and the amount of different books.

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I have created a generalized version that took a similar approach with a `Dictionary<int, int>` to store the book `ID`'s and also stored my discount data in a `Dictionary<int, decimal>`. But I ran into a problem with the algorithm for general discount data (if there are more different books in the basket than the maximum "discounted" number, one basically has to do the same algorithm in a "mini version" again). It's not hard to fix though.

Comment: And somehow it seems strange to me that the `Book` class should know about its discount. I'd have done it the other way around, thinking about it. Imagining a workflow, one could think of a book store putting books on discount; for that, they would (in my view) create a new `DiscountInformation` instance and specify what books to "put in there" instead of placing the discount information inside the books. Thus the same book could be used for multiple discounts (complicated), but also one wouldn't have to update all existing books with a given `Id` if their `DiscountInformation` changes.

Comment: Right about this. The best would be to decouple the discount and the book fully by implementing a class in the middle holding both a book id and a discount id.

Comment: Ah, yes, that seems good and easy to store in a database :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, congratulations on getting a correct solution to this problem, which is far more difficult than it looks at first sight.

I just have a few nit-picks regarding your code:

#### 1. Try using LINQ instead of a more imperative approach, where this helps readability.

For example, in your code, some of the properties of the `BookBasket`:

```
/// <summary>
/// True, if the basket contains only one instance or none of any book.
/// </summary>
public bool IsBasic
{
  get
  {
    foreach (int count in storedBooks)
    {
      if (count != 1 && count != 0)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}


/// <summary>
/// True, iff the basket contains no books (and no negative values).
/// </summary>
public bool IsEmpty
{
  get
  {
    foreach (int count in storedBooks)
    {
      if (count != 0)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// True, if there is no negative number of books.
/// </summary>
public bool IsValid
{
  get
  {
    foreach (int count in storedBooks)
    {
      if (count < 0)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

could be rewritten as follows:

```
public bool IsBasic
{
    get { return storedBooks.All(count => count == 0 || count == 1); }
}

public bool IsEmpty
{
    get { return storedBooks.All(count => count == 0); }
}

public bool IsValid
{
    get { return storedBooks.All(count => count >= 0); }
}
```

In my opinion, in this version of the code the comments are no longer needed.

#### 2. The two `Add` methods in `BookBasket` can be combined into one:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds multiple books, given by a list of ID's.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bookIds">The ID's of the books to add.</param>
public void Add(params int[] bookIds)
{
    foreach (var id in bookIds)
    {
        storedBooks[id - 1]++;
    }
}
```

It's a subjective decision, but I feel like the `Add(int)` method is so simple that it can safely be inlined.

#### 3. The `BookBasket.ToString()` method can be rewritten in a more concise form by taking advantage of the [`String.Join` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Join("", storedBooks);
}
```

#### 4. Sometimes avoiding double `return`s helps readability a bit. In your case, in the body of the `PriceCalc.Price()` method, the memoization of prices can be rewritten from:

```
BookBasket diff = basket - basicBasket;

if (calculatedPrices.ContainsKey(diff))
{
  return calculatedPrices[diff] + basicBasketsAndFactors[basicBasket] * SingleBookPrice;
}
else
{
  decimal diffPrice = Price(diff);
  calculatedPrices.Add(diff, diffPrice);
  return diffPrice + basicBasketsAndFactors[basicBasket] * SingleBookPrice;
}
```

to:

```
BookBasket diff = basket - basicBasket;

if (!calculatedPrices.ContainsKey(diff))
{
  calculatedPrices.Add(diff, Price(diff));
}

return calculatedPrices[diff] +
       basicBasketsAndFactors[basicBasket] *
       SingleBookPrice;
```

This results in slightly less code and I find it a bit more readable.

#### 5. This is the most subjective of all my points: Do not use `#region`s.

I don't find `#region Constructors` and `#region Properties` to help readability in any way; I think it even interferes with the regular flow of the code and [I'm not alone](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53114/30927).

All of the above are minor changes to the form of the code, not fundamental changes to its structure, but I think their cumulative effect is noticeable and makes some parts easier to read/reason about.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful input! I'm far more familiar with LINQ now than I was half a year ago, so I'd have written the properties the way you mentioned nowadays, which makes me happy ;) Great info on the regions as well! I think I already read this once, but our (old) code here mostly uses them and I guess I'm just so used to them I started creating them myself. Will definitely try to change this!